# HOW TO FIX: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'release')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

im writing a jest unit test. it;s kinda weird cause the error it's pointing is way out the current file that im working on.

however, when i ran this specific file it always throws an error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'release')

any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

thanks!

[image]

this is the spec file

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ThankYouComponent } from '../../../modules/thank-you/thank-you.component';

describe('ThankYouComponent', () => {
    let component: ThankYouComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ThankYouComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ThankYouComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ThankYouComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

this is the .ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CheckoutResponse } from 'src/app/models';
import { getCheckoutDetailsSelector } from '../personal-details/state/checkout';
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { MarketingService } from '../contract-confirmation/state/marketing/marketing.service';
import { FeedbackService } from 'src/app/shared/services/thank-you/feedback.service';
import { SetFeedbackAPI } from './state/actions/feedback.action';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import {
    RestrictBackReloading,
    ShowBackButton,
} from 'src/app/state/back-button';
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { thankYouRoutes } from 'src/app/shared/util/constants/router.constant';
import { backReloadingAttributes } from 'src/app/shared/model/common.model';
import { FeedbackParams } from 'src/app/shared/model/feedback.model';
import { SaveMarketing } from '../contract-confirmation/state/marketing';

@Component({
    selector: 'mtn-thank-you',
    templateUrl: './thank-you.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./thank-you.component.scss'],
})
export class ThankYouComponent implements OnInit {
    // id: string;
    label: string;
    unitType: string;
    hint: string;
    errorMessage: string;
    isFloating: boolean;
    showIcon: boolean;
    public agree;
    public offer: CheckoutResponse;
    ratingValue: any;
    ratingForm: FormGroup;
    feedBackRating: number;
    profile: any;
    feedbackKeyword: string;
    paramKeyword: any;
    ratingVariations = [
        {
            value: 0,
            keyword: 'Poor',
            isSelected: false,
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            keyword: 'OK',
            isSelected: false,
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            keyword: 'Good',
            isSelected: false,
        },
        {
            value: 3,
            keyword: 'Great',
            isSelected: false,
        },
        {
            value: 4,
            keyword: 'Epic',
            isSelected: false,
        },
    ];

    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

    constructor(
        private store: Store,
        private marketingService: MarketingService,
        private feedbackService: FeedbackService
    ) {
        this.ratingForm = new FormGroup({
            rating: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            feedback: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        });
        this.store.dispatch(ShowBackButton({ status: false }));
        const reLoadingStatus: backReloadingAttributes = {
            isLoadingEnabled: false,
            routeBackURL: thankYouRoutes,
        };
        this.store.dispatch(RestrictBackReloading(reLoadingStatus));
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.label = 'Floating Label';
        this.hint = '0/30 CHARECTERS';
        this.errorMessage = 'The field is invalid';
        this.isFloating = false;
        this.showIcon = true;
        this.getCheckoutCompositeDetails();
        this.agree = true;
        history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe$.next(true);
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }

    getCheckoutCompositeDetails(): any {
        this.store
            .select(getCheckoutDetailsSelector)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(offer => {
                if (offer) {
                    this.offer = offer;
                }
            });
    }

    getRating(event: any) {
        this.ratingValue = event;
        this.getKeyword(this.ratingValue);
    }

    getKeyword(rating: number) {
        switch (rating) {
            case 0:
                this.feedbackKeyword = this.ratingVariations[0].keyword;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.feedbackKeyword = this.ratingVariations[1].keyword;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.feedbackKeyword = this.ratingVariations[2].keyword;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.feedbackKeyword = this.ratingVariations[3].keyword;
                break;
            case 4:
                this.feedbackKeyword = this.ratingVariations[4].keyword;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    submitRating() {
        const feedbackParams: FeedbackParams = {
            rating: this.ratingValue,
            additionalFeedback: this.ratingForm.get('feedback').value || '',
            feedbackKeywords: [
                {
                    keyword: this.feedbackKeyword,
                },
            ],
        };

        if (feedbackParams.rating != null) {
            this.store.dispatch(SetFeedbackAPI(feedbackParams));
            window.open(`${environment.HOME_PAGE}/`, '_self');
        }
    }

    validateAgree() {
        if (this.agree) {
            this.store.dispatch(SaveMarketing());
        }
    }

    @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event']) onClickBack() {
        history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check if I declared in the test (spec.ts) all the parameters that were injected into the component: for example: service = TestBed.inject(BasicService)